# Shared Preference save Textview background

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have three buttons "Red", "Green" and "Save" and Textview. Whenever I press "Red" or "Green" buttons Textview background color will be changed. I need to save changed background color to Shared preference when I press "Save" button. And I need to open an activity get changed background color. How can I achieve this?

> layout/activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.gela.myexampleeeeeeeeeeeee.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="save"
        android:id="@+id/button_save"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="59dp"
        android:onClick="onClick" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:background="@drawable/red"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="red"
        android:id="@+id/button_red"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:onClick="onClick" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="green"
        android:id="@+id/button_green"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_red"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="onClick" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

> MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    Button button_save, button_red, button_green;
    TextView textView;

    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button_save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_save);
        button_red = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_red);
        button_green = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_green);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

        prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

        // what code for this?

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.button_red:
                textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red);
                break;
            case R.id.button_green:
                textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);
                break;
            case R.id.button_save:
                prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

                //what code for this?


                break;

        }
    }
}
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9b5Lr.jpg)

> drawable/red

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:startColor="#FF4081" android:centerColor="#FF4081" android:endColor="#FF4081"/>
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="50dp" android:bottomRightRadius="50dp" android:topLeftRadius="50dp" android:topRightRadius="50dp"/>
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ffffff" />
            <padding android:left="15dp" android:top="2dp" android:right="15dp" android:bottom="2dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:startColor="#4D000000" android:centerColor="#4D000000" android:endColor="#4D000000"/>
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="50dp" android:bottomRightRadius="50dp" android:topLeftRadius="50dp" android:topRightRadius="50dp"/>
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ffffff" />
            <padding android:left="15dp" android:top="2dp" android:right="15dp" android:bottom="2dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

> drawable/green

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:startColor="#00e676" android:centerColor="#00e676" android:endColor="#00e676"/>
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="50dp" android:bottomRightRadius="50dp" android:topLeftRadius="50dp" android:topRightRadius="50dp"/>
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ffffff" />
            <padding android:left="15dp" android:top="2dp" android:right="15dp" android:bottom="2dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:startColor="#4D000000" android:centerColor="#4D000000" android:endColor="#4D000000"/>
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="50dp" android:bottomRightRadius="50dp" android:topLeftRadius="50dp" android:topRightRadius="50dp"/>
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ffffff" />
            <padding android:left="15dp" android:top="2dp" android:right="15dp" android:bottom="2dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Comment: added more clarity in the question

Answer (score 0):

```
    public String StoreData(String yourKey, String colorName)
    {
       SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("yourFileName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
       editor.putString(yourKey, colorName);
       editor.commit();
    }

    public String SaveData(String keyThatYouUsedToStore)
    {
       SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("yourFileName",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       return sharedPref.getString(keyThatYouUsedToStore, "No String found!");
    }
```

First of all - do not store drawable. Since your drawable does not seem to change during runtime it would be an overkill to store that.

Instead, in my sample you store the name in string of the color. Based on string stored and returned you can then bind appropriate resource. You can store an integer of the resource (i.e. R.id.button_red) however this requires separate research as storing plain R.id.button_red would be unreliable.